# Laravel 5 doubts about image/file upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a small institutional website for my company, and there is going to be a Blog(can only post from backoffice, only for admins). I'm having trouble basically with the image upload. I need to store the image link in the database, but I don't know how to move the uploaded image to my resources folder.

This is my first time working with file upload in Laravel, and the documentation is kind of confusing with the Local Storage and Cloud Storage. I'm not really sure which one I need to use...

I only have this in my template:

```
<label for="image" class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload image</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="image" type="file" name="image" required>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to process this in the controller..

EDIT:

So, after reading more throughly the docs, I think I've understood. Here is what I've got so far:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
     $path = $request->photo->store('image');
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:`Call to a member function store() on null`

I'm using the `public` drive, since everybody can see the blog posts. Any help?

Comment: It's well documented: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Comment: Thanks. I added an EDIT to my question. Please check if possible.

Comment: what does `dd($request->photo);` return ?

Comment: I've managed to fix it. It was returning null. I thought photo was a method, but it's the name of the input field in the template. After that I've managed to do everything else. Thanks.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @Paras I'm using 5.4.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = $request->image->store('images');
```

Comment: Yeah, I already fixed it, but forgot to post the answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage, cloud storage is for example persisting to an Amazon S3 Bucket.

In your controller you can check for and retrieve files using

```
if (Input::file('image'))
{
    // file is set.
    // Move the file.
   Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. In this link: laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files It says to use the store method directly from the `$request` object. And you are saying to use the Facade(?) Input. Which one am I supposed to use?

Comment: I guess it's just preference. I've opted for using the Input Facades in my code in the past but they are only a helpful (less portable) way of doing things. I think this is coming from a L4 background where Facades where more heavily documented.

Comment: I added an EDIT to my question. Please check if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[storing-uploaded-files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

Storing Uploaded Files

To store an uploaded file, you will typically use one of your configured filesystems. The  UploadedFile class has a store method which will move an uploaded file to one of your disks, which may be a location on your local filesystem or even a cloud storage location like Amazon S3.

The store method accepts the path where the file should be stored relative to the filesystem's configured root directory. This path should not contain a file name, since a unique ID will automatically be generated to serve as the file name.

The store method also accepts an optional second argument for the name of the disk that should be used to store the file. The method will return the path of the file relative to the disk's root:

```
$path = $request->photo->store('images');

$path = $request->photo->store('images', 's3');
```

If you do not want a file name to be automatically generated, you may use the storeAs method, which accepts the path, file name, and disk name as its arguments:

```
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');

$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg', 's3');
```